MOSFT Amp Troubleshooting Advice - Low Audible Hum
I'm looking for some advice regarding a simple MOSFET amp channel that I am attempting to repair.
The image attached shows one of the amp's board for a channel. I've replaced the 2 x N-Fets and and 2 P-Fets - supplied by a reputable source whom I trust. When I power the amp up via my bulb tester without speakers plugged in all appears to be fine. As soon as I plug the speakers the bulb in my tester become brighter and there is a low audible hum. I can hear sound but it's very low and sounds almost distorted. The 2 negative MOSFETS are roasting hot though - so I have powered the amp down. I've tried this cycle a few times, amp powered for no more than 10 seconds at a time. I'm testing without the heatsink but I'm certain I've tested in the past very briefly without the heatsink and sound has been fine.
I tried removing all 4 MOSFETs and they all show as good in my basic component tester. The N-Fets are the left two TR1 and TR2 (TR2 is not seated in the photo). I have also lifted a legs of the following resistors which all check out ok:
R2, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20
Capacitor C5 is also ok.
If I switch my input and speaker cable to the working channel sound is fine so I know my source and speakers are functioning correctly.
I'm just about out of ideas, I am an a hobbyest with very basic knowledge looking for some advice or ideas how to troubleshoot this issue of low sound and humming.

EDIT: The orignal N-Fet is a 2SK221 and the P-Fet is 2SJ351, The 221 I've replaced with like for like, the P-Fet I've replaced with a 2SJ352 which I understand it is safe to do with 20V extra in the max permitted voltage

What were the original MOSFETs and what are the replacements?

@vir I've updated my question with the FET details

"supplied by a reputable source whom I trust" I'm not sure how much trust you can have when you, as you yourself state, are "a hobbyist with very basic knowledge looking for some advice". Seasoned professionals sometimes get caught by fake parts. How do you really know you can trust that part source with "basic knowledge" only? This amp should work fine with just about any non-RF power mosfet that has specifications exceeding those of the original. What is the little board floating on 3 wires? Is it original to the amp? I'd start by checking the idle current and output DC voltage (should be ~0

It is extremely easy to get fake parts when looking for out-of-production "audio" mosfets. For the amp of such a simple design, I would just buy modern parts in the same package and with similar or better ratings. And from a reputable big-name supplier like DigiKey, Mouser, Newark, Elfa/Distrelec, etc. You can of course test whether the mosfets work or not by measuring them in-circuit and looking for whether the voltages make sense for an operating mosfet. How did you diagnose that the original problem was bad mosfets? Did they measure as bad when you pulled them out of the amp?

Well, trust in so much as they have positive feedback and other have reported successful fixes with these FETs - of course I can't be absolutely certain but as I said, a trusted source and have met in person. The original failure cam about due to mixing polarity when plugging the board in which literally fried the FETs - they went up in smoke
